# How to add values from checkboxes to 'select' query?

Tags: php, sql, post, checkbox

I have some checkbox like this

```
<form action="tt.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="lvl[]" value="0">0&nbsp
<input type="checkbox" name="lvl[]" value="1">1&nbsp
<input type="checkbox" name="lvl[]" value="2">2&nbsp
<input type="checkbox" name="lvl[]" value="3">3&nbsp
<input type="checkbox" name="lvl[]" value="4">4&nbsp
<input type="submit" value="Ok">
```

How to add values from checked ones to SQL query like this?:

If checked 2 and 4 then
`select name,lvl,team from $table where lvl=2 or lvl=4`
If checked 2 and 4 **AND 0** then 
`select name,lvl,team from $table where lvl=2 or lvl=4 or team='abc'` (if 0 checked then 'select' must contains strings where team='abc', if not - don't)
If none is selected then
`select name,lvl,team from $table`

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$where = '';

if (isset($_POST['lvl']) && $vals = $_POST['lvl']) {

   // Begin WHERE string
   $where = 'WHERE '; 

   // Remove '0' from array
   if ($key = array_search('0', $vals)) {
      $where .= 'team = "abc" ';
      unset($vals[$key]);
   } 

   // Append `WHERE lvl IN (2,4)`
   $where .= 'AND lvl IN (' . implode(',', $vals) . ')';

   // Final statement

}

$sql = "select name,lvl,team from $table $where";
```

---

**Edit**

What happens if you replace this:

```
if ($key = array_search('0', $vals)) {
   $where .= 'team = "abc" ';
   unset($vals[$key]);
}
```

With:

```
if ($vals[0] === '0') {
   $where .= 'team = "abc" ';
   unset($vals[0]);
}
```

---

Change your code to this:

```
$first = false;
if ($vals[0] === '0') {
    $where .= 'team = "neutral"';
    unset($vals[0]);
    $first = true;
}
if (count($vals)) {
    if ($first) $where .= ' OR ';
    $where .= 'lvl IN (' . implode(',', $vals) . ')';
}
```

Comment: demo: http://kraleksandr.dlinkddns.com/tt.php (may be not available)    If I checked 0 and 1, $sql is `SELECT name,lvl,team FROM table WHERE AND lvl IN (0,1)`.

Comment: Are you using all my code? Try `array_search('0', $vals)` instead of `array_search(0, $vals)`

Comment: You're obviously not implementing my code on tt.php because when I select the '0' option, the WHERE statement is not properly constructed. The '0' value has a key of '0' and a value of '0' in the array.

Comment: Can you give me an advice what I must change now?

Comment: What happens when you `var_dump($vals)` after submitting the form with '0' selected?

Comment: If I paste this code before your code it returns NULL. After: array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "0"
}

Comment: See updated answer. Change `$vals[0] === 0` to `$vals[0] === '0'`

Comment: It looks better now, but if I select something except 0 AND 1...8 then sql query isnt valid (Result count in demo)

Comment: Same as previous, but now it works if none checkbox is selected.

Comment: What does it show when you `var_dump($sql)` when no options are selected?

Comment: string(34) "SELECT name,lvl,team FROM portals " (Query: in demo)

Comment: Isn't this what you want? You said you wanted this query in your question when no options are selected...

Comment: Yes. But if I select something, sql query becomes wrong and dont do what I need (look at Result count: in demo)

Comment: If I select options 0,1,2 the SQL query is `SELECT name,lvl,team FROM portals WHERE team = "neutral" OR lvl IN (1,2)` and 420 results are returned...

Comment: But what happens if I want see only 3 and 7?

Comment: Now it works, but if only 0 then query brokes again. Maybe we need to add `OR` with separated `if`?